# Is there a way I can get R to calculate my csv file to show me the percentiles?

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript

I've tried using the quantile function but it doesn't do as intended, I've run out of options, so I'm turning to you R gurus for help.

Assume we are finding the P50 where I mention percentiles.

an example data set would be

```
  Date           data
  2020-01-01      49.5
  2020-02-01      49.7
  2020-03-14      48.5
  2020-05-02      50.2
```

I'm trying to have the script result in a percentile output using the column before it

```
  Date           data    V1     V2      V3
  2020-01-01      49.5   49.6   49.6    49.5625
  2020-02-01      49.7   49.7   49.525
  2020-03-14      48.5   49.35
  2020-05-02      50.2
```

What this tries to accomplish in V1 is finding a percentile using 48.5 and 50.2 in the data column to result in the 49.6 in V1, the result of 49.7 in V1 should be the percentile result of using 50.2, 48.5 and 49.7 etc. Then V2 the result of 49.525 is the result from using the percentiles of 49.35 and 49.7 in V1 and the result 49.6 in V2 is the percentile of 49.35, 49.7, 49.6 etc and in V3 the result of 49.5625 is from finding the percentile from V2 using 49.525 and 49.6

and keep doing this until the entire dataset has been done.

Then when this is done bring down the results without altering the output resulting in:

```
  Date           data    V1     V2      V3
  2020-01-01      49.5   NA     NA      NA
  2020-02-01      49.7   49.6   NA      NA
  2020-03-14      48.5   49.7   49.6    NA
  2020-05-02      50.2   48.35  49.525  49.5625
```

Comment: You say you want to find "the 45th percentile", but it's not clear to me what you are wanting to calculate the 45th percentile *of*.  For example `quantile(1:10,0.45)` evaluates to `5.05`. What do you want to calculate in place of `1:10`? `quantile(c(10,20),0.45)` and `quantile(c(10,20,30),0.45)`?

Comment: I'm basically trying to automate a process that I usually do manually in excel (it takes quite a lot of time to do in excel, averaging 1-2 months) just finding the percentile of each row as it calculates. 

So basically you'll take your first column, copy that column, move up a row in the empty column next to it and paste. After that you move over to the coloumn next to it, and up one row and ask Excel to find whatever percentile you are looking for row by row. you keep doing that in intervals until you reach the beginning date of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual algorithm. I take it when you say 45th percentile you just mean 0.45 times the number in question.

It will be very slow and complex to try to move rows about as you suggest, but you should still be able to get to a solution iteratively. It's not clear from your example exactly what you want (your numbers don't match your description of what is supposed to be happening to your numbers), but from following your description of the algorithm, here is a worked solution. I havd included a longer data frame so you can ensure the numbers match your expectations.

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2002/1/1", "2002/3/2", "2002/4/15",
                                  "2003/1/1", "2003/3/2", "2003/4/15")),
                 Data = 1:6 * 10)

for(i in 2:nrow(df)) df[[i + 1]] <- dplyr::lag(apply(df[-1], 1, sum) * 0.45)

df
#>         Date Data   V3     V4       V5       V6       V7
#> 1 2002-01-01   10   NA     NA       NA       NA       NA
#> 2 2002-03-02   20  4.5     NA       NA       NA       NA
#> 3 2002-04-15   30  9.0 11.025       NA       NA       NA
#> 4 2003-01-01   40 13.5 17.550 22.51125       NA       NA
#> 5 2003-03-02   50 18.0 24.075 31.97250 42.10256       NA
#> 6 2003-04-15   60 22.5 30.600 41.43375 55.82138 74.76753
```

Note that in R, unlike in Excel, you cannot leave cells in a numeric column blank - they will contain `NA`

---

**Update**

Following further information from the OP, the following function carries out the described algorithm. Here `df` is the data frame with "count" in the rightmost column, and you can put whatever percentile you like.

```
make_percentiles <- function(df, percentile = 50)
{
  df_names <- names(df)
  percentile <- percentile/100
  f <- function(x, p) c(NA, x[-length(x)]) + p * c(NA, diff(x))
  while(length(which(!is.na(df[[length(df)]]))) > 1) 
  {
    df <- cbind(df, f(df[[length(df)]], percentile))
  }
  setNames(df, c(df_names, paste0("v", 1:(length(df) - length(df_names)))))
}
```

So now it's as easy as:

```
make_percentiles(df, 50)
#>         Date data    v1     v2      v3
#> 1 2020-01-01 49.5    NA     NA      NA
#> 2 2020-02-01 49.7 49.60     NA      NA
#> 3 2020-03-14 48.5 49.10 49.350      NA
#> 4 2020-05-02 50.2 49.35 49.225 49.2875

make_percentiles(df, 45)
#>         Date data     v1       v2       v3
#> 1 2020-01-01 49.5     NA       NA       NA
#> 2 2020-02-01 49.7 49.590       NA       NA
#> 3 2020-03-14 48.5 49.160 49.39650       NA
#> 4 2020-05-02 50.2 49.265 49.20725 49.31134
```

Comment: Thank you! the percentile was a random percentile I pulled out just as an example, along with the numbers, but this looks like it might work. I'll try it out.

Comment: so I tried the above it doesn't do as intended, I think I have a better example to show you, and I've updated the question to show it.

Comment: @Island868 I'm sorry, even with your update, I don't understand. When you say "finding a percentile using 48.5 and 50.2 in the data column to result in the 48.4". What does this mean? How exactly do you get 48.4 from 48.5 and 50.2? How is this a percentile?

Comment: I'm using it as an example, say it is the median (P50), so basically when I said the percentile lets assume the the P50  from the data column of 48.5 and 50.2 results in 48.4 ( I know this isn't the actual P50). 

Btw, would it be more helpful if I actually calculated a P50 in excel and replace the example with the actual figures?

Comment: made the updates to the numbers using the percentile function in excel to get them.

Comment: @Island868 see my update. The extra information definitely helped. When you're looking for a specific numeric output you need to have the numbers as expected to give people a clue, particularly if it's clear from comments and downvotes that people are confused about exactly what you want!

Comment: I tried the above, but for some reason it isn't giving me an accurate result. I doubled checked in excel and ran the script again using the dataset I gave you. the results are the same in your above result... but it isn't accurate. 

I tried to figure out why and it seems that the suggested code only tries to find the percentile from the number in its left row and the number directly below the number in the left row, instead of the example where it tries to find the percentile for the number directly in its left row and all numbers below the number in the left row.